# Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue in AJAX in PHP web page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello i am trying to do GET through ajax here is what the error we are getting

```
Failed to load resource: Origin http://www.kashikart.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://recharge.kashikart.com/api/recharge.php?uid=6b687274&pin=312556cbe3&number=7869386777&operator=1&circle=14&amount=10&usertx=foduu&format=JSON&version=4. Origin http://www.kashikart.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

We are just trying to do a normal ajax.

From main domain to sub-domain. But it seems like there is some issue with this. We use these two header on the top of our file from where the ajax request is passing in PHP. Here is how its look like:

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
 header("Origin: http://www.kashikart.com");
 ?>
```

I try to put the header in the .htaccess file as well. But didn't work.

Why its not allowing to call a request on on sub-domain? Suggest will be highly appreciate.

Thank you! (advance)

Comment: You server needs to provide 3 headers : `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`,  `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`

Comment: How can i do that? Any reference?

Comment: google the error ... you will find volumes of information

Comment: I tried but seems like nothing is working for me.

Comment: Look up for "CORS". One thing I'm almost sure is that your server should not send this "Origin: http://www.kashikart.com" header.

Comment: I added all 3 headers. But seems like problem is not resolved.

Comment: This solution is well rounded http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/1175966

Comment: possible duplicate of [CORS with php headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers)